# Wordpress new site with Polish letters

Tags: php, html, wordpress, polish

I have a problem with polish letters in wordpress. I added a new site into wordpress and convet it to php from html and in header i can write letter like "ęą" but in body i can't. I see such thing like: "�꿟". I search entire wordpress and nothing. Maybe someone have idea how to do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using utf-8 characters? Here'a list for Polish characters: http://webdesign.about.com/od/localization/l/blhtmlcodes-pl.htm

Ensure that you have `<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />`
as a meta tag and you should be set. Plop this into your header, and it'll all be gravy. For "ęą" use `&#281;` and `&#261;` respectively

### EDIT:

Unrelated to the question, but if you are using Wordpress for a multi-lingual site check out the `_e` Wordpress function. I've used it before and it's treated me well http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/_e